# Where is defined the proxy configuation for the Software & Update additional Drivers download?

Tags: 22.04, proxy

I am using Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS.
I had in the past configured a proxy, but my work environment changed, and I don't need one anymore.
I removed every single instance I could find of my proxy setup.

Everything is running fine, including Apt or wget and I can perform apt updates and upgrade successfully.

BUT,

When I open the *Software & Update* GUI application, go to the *Additional Drivers*, I can see a list of the nvidia proprietary drivers I want to install. Fine. But if I click to install the nvidia-driver-535 for instance I have an error message:

[image]

That message contains a reference to my old proxy IP address: 10.2.64.3:3128

But if I install the package using the command:

```
sudo apt install nvidia-driver-535
```

it works perfectly fine.

I thought that there is a reference to that proxy in a config file somewhere. Thus, I ran:

```
sudo grep -r / -e '10\.2\.64\.3'
```

It found some files where that string is present, but it is always commented out when in a config file, or part of some log file.
Nothing relevant.

Then I used the dconf-editor to look for instance of Proxy related stuff, nothing here.

No environment variable:

```
env | grep -i proxy
```

returns nothing.

I have no idea where the *Software & Update* stores its proxy data...

How do I remove that proxy setting in the *Software & Update* app ?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, After more digging I found...

I had to look at the source of *software-properties* here:

https://git.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/software-properties/tree/

looks like that tool is using PackageKitGlib 1.0 for doing its package install stuff.

And PackageKitGlib 1.0 stores its proxy config into a SQLite database located here:

/var/lib/PackageKit/transactions.db

By opening that database using a SQLite browser, I found out that the proxy settings are stored here. I removed the entries of the proxy table and it works!

But I am sure that this should be automatically updated somehow when removing proxy setting with the gnome GUI...